# SPA, Web API Bearer Token security issues

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token

Bearer: means a person or thing that carries or holds something.

It means login once, say, by angular app, and can be used from anywhere like postman or fiddle or from any other website by using the same token.

In Angular 4, we can store the token either in cookie/localstorage/sessionstorage but it can be easily accessed and used.

So how to protect our token and Web API to use token only from where it was created.

Answer (score 0):

If the token is only in cookie, try putting httponly on the cookie. Also try setting up samesite=strict or similar property on the cookie. That way it will only be available to your website.

Note: SameSite is currently only supported in latest webkit or blink based browsers.

Comment: HTTP only cookie will not be available to Javascript framework ..